# All records being deleted when deleting records from a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I am passing a string of documentIDs to and its supposed to delete the documentID where its roleID = @roleID, but instead it is deleting all the records based on the roleID and all I want to do is delete the documentIDs from the table based on the roleID

My sp is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_RemoveDocumentIDsFromRole
(
@roleID int,
@group_name varchar(50),
@DocumentIDString varchar(500),
@group_display_name varchar(50)
)
as
UPDATE [master_groups] 
set group_name = @group_name, @group_display_name = @group_display_name
where roleID = @roleID

-- Creating Variables
DECLARE @numberLength int
DECLARE @numberCount int
DECLARE @TheDocumentIDs VarChar(500)

DECLARE @sTemp VarChar(100) -- to hold single characters

    -- Creating a temp table
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
    TheDocumentIDs VarChar(500)
)
--Initializing Variables for counting 
SET @numberLength = LEN (@DocumentIDString)
SET @numberCount = 1
SET @TheDocumentIDs = ''

--Start looping through the keyword ids
WHILE (@numberCount <= @numberLength)

BEGIN
SET @sTemp = SUBSTRING (@DocumentIDString, @numberCount, 1)
    IF (@sTemp = ',')
        BEGIN
            INSERT @T(TheDocumentIDs) VALUES (@TheDocumentIDs)
            SET @TheDocumentIDs = ''
        END
    IF (@sTemp <> ',')
        BEGIN
            SET @TheDocumentIDs = @TheDocumentIDs + @sTemp
        END
        SET @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
END 

declare @rLevel int
set @rLevel = 0

delete from [master_group_document_relations] where exists(select documentID = @TheDocumentIDs from @T) and roleID = @roleID
```

**UPDATE: SAMPLE DATA**
[image: Sample Data]

Comment: @EmmadKareem, I am pretty sure its correct, its selecting the ids from the temp table and supposed to delete them. I use the same way as inserting a temp table of ids to a table

Comment: one question and one suggestion. Q: Can you provide example on about input DocumentIDString and after processing about the content of  table T ? Suggestion: avoid using "sp_"  as prefix for your stored procedures. "sp_" is also used as prefix by Microsoft SQL Server build-in stored procedures and this is a no-no (you can confirm this by searching on Books Online if interested).

Comment: @EduardUta, yea I am guilty of prefixing with sp_, I was already aware that it was a no-no, but its for testing until I get ready to clean up the code..The DocumentIDString looks like.. 123,234,321, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you get in **@TheDocumentIDs**, but I suppose it should work for you.

First of all as **@Chris** mentioned, you should check put condition to where clause and as documentIds is a list of id's it should used with **IN** condition and not equality, that's why you need or use **sp_executesql** or fill id's to a **temp table**.

```
         EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          N'delete from [master_group_document_relations] 
            where documentID IN (@TheDocumentIDs) 
               and roleID = @roleID',
          N'@TheDocumentIDs varchar(500), @roleID int',
          @DocumentIDString,
          @roleID;
```

Or try this

```
            delete from [master_group_document_relations] 
            where documentID IN (SELECT TheDocumentIDs FROM @T) 
               and roleID = @roleID
```

Comment: I tried this also and the ID that should have been removed is still there

Comment: @Chris what about 2nd query?

Comment: Sorry the 2nd query didn't work and I don't know how to run the first query

Comment: @Chris Just put it in your sp instead of your delete statement.

Comment: @Chris what are the values for T and TheDocumentIDs before delete?

Comment: @Chris please, try the 1st query one more time, I've used DocumentIDString instead of TheDocumentIDs

Comment: I just edited and added a pic of the data. I don't know how to run the 1rst one. The documentIDString would be like 149,150, and it should remove both documentIDs and the roleId so when I query again, i'll only have documentID 142 and roleID 161

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete records of `master_group_document_relations` where its `documentID` is in `TheDocumentIDs` of `@t` and `roleID` is equal to `@roleID` then try this :

```
DELETE T1
FROM   [master_group_document_relations] AS T1
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   @T AS T2
              WHERE  T1.documentID = T2.TheDocumentIDs)
       AND roleID = @roleID
```

Comment: Threw an error for invalid column name T1.documentID

Comment: sorry edited the answer. I took same alias both tables.

Comment: I tried it and the result came back that the ID wasn't deleted.

Comment: it should have worked or I am perceiving it incorrectly. check this sql fiddle for above query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41126

Comment: Updated with a pic of the data